# É possível usar let e var no mesmo loop for?

Tags: javascript

No codigo abaixo seria interessante se eu pudesse definir i como let e poder manter pass como var, tem como fazer isso sem ser declarando pass numa linha acima?

```
const randPass = () => {
    for (var i = 0, pass = ""; i < 8; i++) {
        pass = `${pass}${randChar()}`;
    }
    return pass;
}
```

Comment: Porque quer usar let e var? Existe algum motivo específico?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes declarar os dois com `let` usando `,`, na mesma linha. Mas se queres que o retorno da função seja `pass` então tens de dar `return` dentro do loop assim:

```js
function randChar() {
  return Math.random().toString(36).slice(-1);
}

const randPass = () => {
  for (let i = 0, pass = ""; i < 8; i++) {
    pass = `${pass}${randChar()}`;
    if (i == 7) return pass;
  }
  
}

console.log(randPass());
```

Senão tens de defenir a variável fora do loop e depois dar return:

```js
function randChar() {
  return Math.random().toString(36).slice(-1);
}

const randPass = () => {
  let pass = ""
  for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    pass = `${pass}${randChar()}`;
  }
  return pass;
}

console.log(randPass());
```